# Segmentation Fault running time on sem_post(flag)

Tags: c, linux, semaphore

I'm getting a segmentation fault posting to a semaphore. The actual crash is on this line:

```
sem_post(flag);
```

Here's the code I'm using:

```
//global variable for the use of all threads:
sem_t *flag= NULL;


//in main,before creating the threads:
sem_init(flag,0,1);


//in function of the threads :
sem_post(flag);
```

I tried also using simply a global semaphore - in place of - pointer to semaphore. How do I fix this?

Comment: "*I tried also using simply a global semaphore - in place of - pointer to semaphore.*" -- if you want us to address this, then you'll need to present actual code that demonstrates exactly what you did, preferably in the form of a [mre].

Answer (score 2):

I believe that you are using the `sem_t *` type in a way that is plausible but incorrect. Rather than having your semaphore itself be a `sem_t *`, which means "I'm not a `sem_t`, but I can tell you where one is," you'll want that semaphore to have type `sem_t`.

As a result, when you call `sem_init`, you'll need to pass in the address of your semaphore, as shown here:

```
sem_init(&flag, 0, 1);
```

Similarly, to post to the semaphore, you'll want to write

```
sem_post(&flag);
```

Let's contrast that with what you're doing right now. By making `flag` a `sem_t *` that points to `NULL`, you're saying "I point to a semaphore, except that I'm not actually pointing at one." Calling `sem_init` and passing in a null pointer is an error - that would mean "please construct a semaphore at the location pointed at by a null pointer," which is semantically incorrect. The crash you're getting occurs because you're similarly saying "please post to the semaphore pointed at by this null pointer." By instead having an honest-to-goodness semaphore object that you then pass into the functions, you're saying "here's my semaphore - please do nice things with it."

Comment: Thank u , your explanation is  good ,I think I got your idea ,  I'm aware that I'm using a pointer to  semaphore , we learnt in the class , that we can use pointers to abbreviate the use of &. I tried again your suggestion , but I got more errors. here some  of them :x.c:101:2: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘sem_init’ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
  sem_init(&flag,0,1);

Comment: Careful - the purpose of pointers is *not* to abbreviate the use of `&`. Did you change the definition of `flag` so that it's now a `sem_t`, not a `sem_t *`?

Comment: @reham.abass, using a variable of pointer type *does not* "abbreviate" use of `&`.  It merely gives you a variable that can store the result of an `&` expression.  The key problem here is that somewhere there needs to be an actual `sem_t` for the pointer to point **to**, and the code you present in the question does not provide one.